# Executar redirecionamento pelo getJSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo a tela de login usando `getJSON`. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer o redirecionamento assim que for sucesso.

A ideia do redirecionamento ficar no `login.php` é para não ficar muito exposto o código JavaScript.

**arquivo LOGIN.PHP**

```
$Array[] = Array(
    "sucesso" => "<script>window.location='painel.php'</script>",
);
$json_encode = json_encode($Array);
echo $json_encode;
```

**arquivo INDEX.PHP**

```
$("#acessar").click(function() {
    usuario = $("#usuario").val();
    senha = $("#senha").val();

    // carregamos o JSON passando o nome
    $.getJSON("login.php", {usuario:usuario, senha:senha}, function(json){

        json[0].sucesso;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa apenas retornar a URL de direcionamento, e não um script.

Altere a array no PHP para retornar apenas a URL desejada:

```
$Array[] = Array(
    "sucesso" => "painel.php",
);
```

E no Ajax você redireciona desta forma:

```
$.getJSON("login.php", {usuario:usuario, senha:senha}, function(json){
   location.href = json[0].sucesso;
});
```

Comment: Sam, esta dando erro interno no servidor quando uso `location.href = json[0].sucesso;`

Comment: Não deveria dar erro de servidor, porque esse código é JavaScript.

Comment: Resolvi, dentro do `getJSON` eu tenho um `IF` que verifica se retornou com sucesso ou não. Coloquei no `else` e deu certo.